# Component is missing after rerendering

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I want to create an SQL Editor. For that I need to display to which database I am currently connected to.

If I select some Database from the Dropdown Menu the Dropdown component will disappear completely.

Btw: I use the bootstrap library for Dropdown Menus

Here is what I got so far:

**App.js**

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Switch from "react-bootstrap/Switch";
import {Route, useParams} from "react-router";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import {useState} from "react";
import QueryPage from "./components/QueryPage";
import ChangeDB from "./components/essentials/ChangeDB";



function App() {
    const [connections, setConnections] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            dbname: "db1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            dbname: "db2"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            dbname: "db3"
        }]
    );
    const [db, setDB] = useState(1);

    const onDBChange = ({id}) => {
        setDB(() => id)
    }
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header database={db} connections={connections}/>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/home","db/:id" ]}>
                <QueryPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/db/:id"><ChangeDB callback={onDBChange} /></Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
import {Button, Form, FormControl, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown} from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Header.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Header({ database , connections}) {
    alert(database);
    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
            <Logo />
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">fnmSQL Client</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                    {connections.map(con => {
                        if(con.id === database) {
                            return (
                                <NavDropdown title={con.dbname} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                    {connections.length !== 0 ?
                                        connections.filter(id => (database !== id)).map(con => (
                                            <NavDropdown.Item className={"bootstrap-overrides"} href={"#db/" + con.id}>{con.dbname}</NavDropdown.Item>
                                        ))
                                        :
                                        <NavDropdown.Item disabled="true">No Database Connections</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    }
                                </NavDropdown>
                            )
                        }
                    })}

                </Nav>
                <Form inline>
                    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                    <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                </Form>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
}

const Logo = () => {
    return (
        <Link to="./">
        <img src={LogoWhite} alt={"ADVA Optical Networking SE"} className={"img"}/>
        </Link>
    )
}


export default Header;
```

I havent found another solution to read from HashRouter than putting it in some extra Component:

**ChangeDB.js**

```
function ChangeDB({callback}) {
    let id = useParams();
    callback(id);
    return null;
}

export default ChangeDB;
```

Comment: Is "the Dropdown Menu the Dropdown component" your `Header` component? Additionally, I don't think this is related to your issue, but within the `Switch` component the path order and specificity matters. You want to order them most specific to least specific, i.e. `path={["/db/:id", "/home", "/" ]`. Also, the first `Route`'s "/db/:id" path covers the second `Route` on the same path if the second ends up not being more specific.

Comment: The Header component consists of some other Navbar parts plus my Dropdown menu where you can select the database. Good thing with the path I will implement that.

Comment: I've looked at the react-bootstrap docs and it isn't clear to me if the `NavDropdown.Item` components are links or not, but I suspect the `href` attribute is mucking with your app navigation. Are you trying to select those from the dropdown list and immediately navigate to that path, i.e. push to "/db/someIdValue"?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. It was because of the strict equality operator.
It seems that either database or con.id is parsed as a string instead of an integer.
I don't know why maybe somebody got an explanation...

Cheers guys